# PHP assign first not-null value

Tags: php, variables

I've got some three values like this:

```
$a = null
$b = 3;
$c = null
```

(I never know what will be `null`: maybe all of them, maybe none of them.)

Following so called *lazy loading*, I've tried to assign the **first** not-null value this way:

```
$d = $a or $b or $c;
```

(It is similar to JavaScript way `var d = a || b;` (it will assign b if there is no a).)

But in PHP it seems to not work.

Am I doing it wrong, or what is best and simplest way to do this?

Comment: Folks, don't accept _minor edits_ like [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/suggested-edits/789112)

Comment: PHP converts this to: ($d = $a) or $b or $c; which returns true

Comment: I need value, not boolean.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

You can use the short ternary operator in PHP 5.3+:

```
$d = $a ?: $b ?: $c;
```

Note that this does type coercion like in JS.

---

**Update (PHP 7)**

In PHP 7.0+ you would do (called `null coalescing` - [more informations](http://php.net/manual/en/migration70.new-features.php#migration70.new-features.null-coalesce-op)):

```
$d = $a ?? $b ?? $c;
```

Comment: @hsz: Added for clarification.

Comment: @Kluska000: I guess type coercion is what I meant. `'' == 0 == false == null`. More here http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.type-juggling.php

Comment: Ha! Just noticed this question was updated to add my answer (though without any mention of the subtleties) just a couple of hours after I made it. That's the way to build up reputation!

Answer (score 6):

In PHP 7 you can use the "Null coalescing" operator:

```
$d = $a ?? $b ?? $c;
```

This will assign the first non-null value (or null if there isn't one), as the question asked.

Unlike some of the other answers it won't be tripped up by implicit type casting so, for example,

```
$b = 0; $c = 1;
$d = $a ?? $b ?? $c;
echo $d;
```

will output 0: It won't mind that $a hasn't been set at all and won't pass over $b even though it type-casts to `false`.

Answer (score 4):

Try this...

```
$d = array_filter(array($a, $b, $c))[0]; //newer PHP only
```

or this:

```
$d = current(array_filter(array($a, $b, $c))); //warning about references
```

or this:

```
$tmp = array_filter(array($a, $b, $c));
$d = current($tmp); //most safe
```

Comment: This is the better solution when you have an arbitrary or unknown number of values that you want to coalesce.

Answer (score 1):

If you can put variables in an array this can help:

```
$d = current(array_filter(array($a, $b, $c)));
```

or this can be a apporach as well:

```
if(!empty($a)) {
 $d = $a;

}
```

this check may conitnue for all the variables like `$b` and `$c`

Answer (score 0):

You can try with:

```
$d = !is_null($a) ? $a : (!is_null($b) ? $b : $c);
```

Answer (score 0):

in php you can do it like this:-

```
`<?php
 $a = 1;
 $b = null;
 $c = null;
 $d = $a ? $a:($b?$b:($c?$c:'null'));
echo $d;
?>`
```

Comment: You shouldn't, though. That is terrible to read.